# How to prove if $a_n$ and $b_n$ converge and $a_n,b_n \ge 0$ then $a_n b_n$ also conveges?.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $a_n$ and $b_n$ are sequences of non-negative numbers and both converge, how do I argue that $\sum a_n b_n$ also converges?

My attempt:

I tried to argue that $a_n b_n\le(a_n+b_n)^2=a_n^2+2a_nb_n+b_n^2$, but I am stuck on how to proceed from here.. I have a feeling that I should use the comparison test, but I am not too sure.

Comment: This is clearly false as stated. Let $a_n = b_n = 1$ for all $n$. Do you mean "and both $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge"?

Comment: Assuming you mean that the series $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge, note that when $x \geq 0$ is small, $x^2 \leq x$. Therefore the tail of $\sum a_n^2$ is smaller than the tail of $\sum a_n$, so since the latter converges, so does the former. Similarly for $b_n$.

Comment: For your inequality, try $0 \leq (a_n - b_n)^2 = a_n^2 - 2a_n b_n + b_n^2$, hence $a_n b_n \leq \frac{1}{2}(a_n^2 + b_n^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition stated in your post isn't clear. You could have $a_n = b_n = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\to 0$, but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n} = \infty$. Thus the said conditions about $a_n$ and $b_n$ should be:  $a_n$ converges, $b_n$ converges, and either $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converges. We can proceed from this point. Let's say $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges. Since $b_n$ converges,it is a bounded sequence, i.e. $|b_n| \le K, \forall n \ge 1$. We have: $0 \le a_nb_n \le Ka_n\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n \le K\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$. This shows the series in question converges by comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

一）If an and bn are sequences of non-negative numbers and both converge, how do I argue that sum ∑anbn  also converges?

you can disprove it by plug in an=1/√n ,  bn=1/√n
∑aₙbₙ=∑1/n⇒+∞, is not a convergent sequence.

二)However, if the problem is:
If ∑an and ∑bn are sequences of non-negative numbers and both converge, how do I argue that sum ∑anbn  also converges?

proof:
for any N
LET ∑aₙbₙ=a៷b៷+...aₙbₙ
<（a៷+a៷₊₁+...aₙ)(b៷+...+bₙ)

because ∑an ,∑bn are convergent sequence,
thus for any ε>0, there exist  N,
∑an=a៷+a៷₊₁+...aₙ+...<ε
∑bn=b៷+...+bₙ+...<ε

hence ∑aₙbₙ=a៷b៷+...aₙbₙ+...<a៷b៷+...aₙbₙ<
（a៷+a៷₊₁+...aₙ)(b៷+...+bₙ)<(a៷+a៷₊₁+...aₙ+...)(b៷+...+bₙ+...)
<ε²=β

So.that.we have conclude that for any β>0, there is N
partial sum ∑aₙbₙ=a៷b៷+...aₙbₙ+...<β
so  ∑aₙbₙ is a Cauchy sequence, and it converge